# Как наиболее точно измерить потребляемую программой память?

Tags: c++, память

Как наиболее точно измерить потребляемую программой память?

При создании вектора я могу, например, сделать обёрточный класс, который будет логировать его размер и умножать этот размер на размер хранимого типа. Но как узнавать размер объектов на стеке? После каждого создания делать `sizeof` кажется непрактичным.

Интересует не столько произвольный момент времени, как максимальное количество, которое в какой-либо момент потребляла программа.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116041/discussion-on-question-by-spider------).

Comment: @Grundy за что?

Comment: В комментарии выше указано: просто слишком много комментариев, поэтому их переносят в чаты и там продолжают обсуждение.

Comment: @Grundy я не могу там писать...

Comment: Вообще должен был мочь, однако можешь посмотреть данный ответ: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3433/186999